# How to express STFT and ISTFT as a 1d convolution and 1d deconvolution in tensorflow/keras

Tags: dft, convolution, stft, deconvolution, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.03107v1) paper in tensorflow and keras. At the end of section 3 it says.

```
Note that although weighted SDR loss is a time-domain loss function,
it can be backpropagated through our framework.
Specifically, STFT and ISTFT operations are implemented as 1-D convolution
and deconvolution layers consisting of fixed filters initialized 
with the discrete Fourier transform matrix.
```

How would I go about implementing an STFT and an ISTFT as a 1-D convolution and 1-D deconvolution respectively? For example how would the window size and the hop length correspond to parameters of a convolution?

Conversely, could I just use tensorflow's built in STFT and inverse_STFT ops instead?

Comment: why we need to use conv1d instead of normal STFT, is it the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an implementation of STFT based on `conv1d` in pytorch here:

https://github.com/huyanxin/phasen/blob/master/model/conv_stft.py

edit: Actually, the phasen repository took the STFT code from https://github.com/pseeth/torch-stft
edit2: Asteroid has an alternative implementation of STFT and iSTFT: https://github.com/mpariente/asteroid/